# Java SELECT query You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: java, mysql

I'm getting the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Date = '2015-04-26' ORDER BY TraceNum' at line 1

This is the query

```
"SELECT Name, sporecount.* FROM sporesfungi INNER JOIN sporecount ON sporesfungi.IDSpore = sporecount.IDSpore WHERE Date = ? ORDER BY TraceNum";
```

If I remove the WHERE clause the query works just fine.

This is the full code

```
public void exportToExcel(String date) throws IOException, BiffException, 
 WriteException, SQLException, ParseException{
 Db_Connect  connection = new Db_Connect();
 conn = connection.connect();



 String originalFile = "C:\\Users\\Geni\\Desktop\\Book1-Template-new.xls";   
 date = date.replace("/", "-");
 SimpleDateFormat myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

 try{
        Workbook original = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(originalFile));
        WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(date+".xls"), original);

        java.util.Date format = myDate.parse(date);
        java.sql.Date newDate = new java.sql.Date(format.getTime());

        String sql = "SELECT Name, sporecount.* FROM sporesfungi "
        + "INNER JOIN sporecount ON sporesfungi.IDSpore = sporecount.IDSpore"
                + "WHERE Date = ? ORDER BY TraceNum";

        PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setDate(1, newDate);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        /*stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);*/


        WritableSheet sheet = copy.getSheet(0);
        WritableCell cell;
        String spore;

        while(rs.next()){
            for(int i = 2; i < 64 ;i++){
                cell = sheet.getWritableCell(1,i);
                spore =  cell.getContents();
                if(rs.getString("Name").equals(spore)){
                   Number l1 = new Number(14-rs.getInt("TraceNum"),i,rs.getInt("Amount")) ;
                   sheet.addCell(l1);

                    }

            }
        }


        copy.write();
        copy.close();
        original.close();
    }
    catch (BiffException | IOException e) {
    }


}
```

Comment: Judging by the code sample, you need a space before the `WHERE`

Comment: Omg can't believe it was something that simple, thank you it worked!

Comment: Added as answer so it can be properly marked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no space before the WHERE.